# как исправить наложение фрагментов viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Есть ViewPager в него входят основные фрагменты и есть фрагменты которые открываются по кнопке из другого фрагмента, как сделать так чтобы они не накладывались, а открывались отдельно и при нажатии на кнопку назад возвращались к исходному фрагменту из которого был вызван, который находится в viewpager

код MainActivity

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentAccount;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentAmenities;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentBalance;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentContainer;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentDocumentation;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentInternetConfiguration;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentMenu;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentNotification;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentOperation;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentSetupTV;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.fragments.FragmentStatistics;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FragmentAccount fragmentAccount;
    FragmentBalance fragmentBalance;
    FragmentAmenities fragmentAmenities;
    FragmentDocumentation fragmentDocumentation;
    FragmentNotification fragmentNotification;
    FragmentOperation fragmentOperation;
    FragmentStatistics fragmentStatistics;
    FragmentInternetConfiguration fragmentInternetConfiguration;
    FragmentSetupTV fragmentSetupTV;
    FragmentMenu fragmentMenu;
    FragmentContainer fragmentContainer;

    final String TAG ="myLog";
    SharedPreferences sPref;


    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    final String SAVED_First = "saved_first";
    final String SAVED_Sur = "saved_sur";
    final String SAVED_Second = "saved_second";
    final String SAVED_Contract = "saved_contract";
    final String SAVED_ContractDate = "saved_contractData";

    private String myFirstName;
    private String mySurName;
    private String mySecondName;
    private String myContract;
    private String myContractDate;


    final String SAVED_AccountId ="saved_accountId";
    final String SAVED_BalanceSum ="saved_balanceSum";
    final String SAVED_OverdraftSum = "saved_overdraftSum";
    final String SAVED_PaySum = "saved_paySum";
    final String SAVED_PayDate = "saved_payDate";

    private String myAccountId;
    private String myBalanceSum;
    private String myOverdraftSum;
    private String myPaySum;
    private String myPayDate;
    private Fragment FragmentBalance;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  /*      String priceHint = getString(R.string.main_price_hint);
        CharSequence spannedPriceHint = spanWithRoubleTypeface(priceHint);
        rub.setHint(spannedPriceHint);
*/

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        fragmentAccount = new FragmentAccount();
        fragmentBalance = new FragmentBalance();
        fragmentAmenities = new FragmentAmenities();
        fragmentDocumentation = new FragmentDocumentation();
        fragmentNotification = new FragmentNotification();
        fragmentOperation = new FragmentOperation();
        fragmentStatistics = new FragmentStatistics();
        fragmentInternetConfiguration = new FragmentInternetConfiguration();
        fragmentSetupTV = new FragmentSetupTV();
        fragmentMenu = new FragmentMenu();
        fragmentContainer = new FragmentContainer();


      Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_toolbar);

        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentMenu);
                ftrans.addToBackStack(null);
                ftrans.commit();
            }
        });

       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentContainer)
                .commit();



    }
```

код FragmentContainer

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.R;
import com.example.navigationdraweractivity.TabsAdapter;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentContainer.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentContainer#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentContainer extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentContainer() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentContainer.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentContainer newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentContainer fragment = new FragmentContainer();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Баланс"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Услуги"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Поступления и списания"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Уведомления"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Статистика"));
        final ViewPager viewPager =(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        TabsAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            /*throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                                               + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно больше деталей. Вообще можно сделать как-то так: 1. ViewPager поместить во фрагмент. 2. Другие фрагменты добавлять/заменять поверх фрагмента с ViewPager.

Comment: можно поподробнее про то как ViewPager поместить во фрагмент?

Comment: Ну... Просто переносите код из активити во фрагмент и всё. Разве что нужно вместо `getSupportFramentManager()` использовать `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста еще при использовании `getChildFragmentManager()` надо использовать `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` но как только я перехожу на эту библиотеку проблема возникает в этом куске кода`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentContainer)
                .commit();` подчеркивается fragmentContainer

Comment: Вместо `fragmentContainer` у вас, по идее, должен быть собственно фрагмент, который вы хотите отобразить. Надо ещё учесть, что фаргмент поверх ViewPager надо отображать из активити, а не из этого (или внутренних) фрагментов. Иначе у вас будет та же проблема что и изначально.

Comment: это проблема возникает как раз таки в активити и fragmentContainer  это сам фрагмент полученный в активити такой строкой кода   `fragmentContainer = new FragmentContainer();`

Comment: Я уже запутался) Покажите весь код. По идее не должно быть проблем с классами фрагментов. Возможно, вам надо вместо `getFragmentManager()` использовать `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: код добавил в описании вопроса

Comment: Ну, по идее просто замените getFragmentManager() на getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Спасибо все получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. Перенести ViewPager из активити во фрагмент. Для этого в адаптер надо будет передавать не FragmentManager активити, но `getChildFragmentManager()` фрагмента, в котором будет ViewPager.
2. Другой фрагмент открывать поверх фрагмента из п.1. - так фрагмент с ViewPager и другой фрагмент будут находиться в одном и том же контейнере и будут корректно заменяться.